# Distinguish two equal variables?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, symbolic-math

everybody. I have this expression

```
expr = (A (n1 - n1^2 + n2 + 2 n1 n2 - n2^2) + 
c ((-1 + n1) n1 - (1 + 2 n1) n2 + n2^2) + 
n1 (1 - n1 + n2) \[Gamma]1 + (1 + n1 - n2) n2 \[Gamma]2)/(B (1 + n1 +
n2))
```

I wish to simplify it, with the assumption n1=n2 and n1 + n2 = N. However, I want to keep the distinction between the two variables.

I should find

> (N (A - c + (n2 [Gamma]2 * n1 [Gamma]1) / N)/(B (1 + N))

However I don't know how to enter the assumptions, because n1 == n2 replaces the variable.

```
Simplify[expr, {n1 == n2, n1 + n2 == n}]
```

I find the solution below and at the numerator n1 disappears

```
(n2 (2 A - 2 c + \[Gamma]1 + \[Gamma]2))/(b (1 + n1 + n2))
```

Thanks in advance if you have an answer

Comment: What you are asking is simply not well posed.  How is simplify to know where to use the rule and where not?   Don't use capital `N` as a variable BTW, it is a built in symbol.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the coefficients of `gamma1,gamma2` should be `n1,n2` you can get there with a temporary substitution to hold the symbol through the other substitution..

```
expr /. 
   { \[Gamma]1 ->  Hold[n1] \[Gamma]1 (2/n)  , \[Gamma]2 ->  
     Hold[n2] \[Gamma]2 (2/n) , n2 -> n/2, n1 -> n/2 } // 
  Simplify // ReleaseHold

(expr /. 
     { n1 \[Gamma]1 ->  n1tmp \[Gamma]1   , 
      n2 \[Gamma]2 ->  n2tmp  \[Gamma]2 } /. {n1 -> n/2, n2 -> n/2} //
    Simplify ) /. {n1tmp -> n1 , n2tmp -> n2}
```

both give

> (A n - c n + n1 [Gamma]1 + n2 [Gamma]2)/(B + B n)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and  I am sorry if I wasn't clear.  Nevertheless I don't feel that it is the best method. Because it can't be generalised if I don't know the final expression. 
For instance, if I took the expression A (n1 - n1^2 + n2 + 2 n1 n2 - n2^2)
I wish that mathematica do : A( n1 + n2 + n1(**2 n2-n1**) - n2^2) =
A( n1 + n2 +n1n2 - n2^2) = A(n1+n2 + n2(**n1-n2**)= A(n1+n2) = AN

Comment: if you cant explain what you want mathematically there isnt much else you can do.